# allCase enum with parameter

Tags: swift, enums

How can I implement a protocol, or alternative solutions, to have in each case all those of the parameter. Something like `League.teamA (.allCases)`

```
import Cocoa

enum PlayerA: CaseIterable {
    case center
    case powerForward
    case smallForward
}

enum PlayerB: CaseIterable {
    case pointGuard
    case shootingGuard
}

protocol EnumProtocol {
    var description: String { get }
}

enum League: EnumProtocol {
    case teamA(PlayerA)
    case teamB(PlayerB)
}

extension League {
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case let .teamA(player):
            switch player {
            case .center: return "Center"
            case .smallForward: return "Small Forward"
            case .powerForward: return "Power Forward"
            }
        case let .teamB(player):
            switch player {
            case .pointGuard: return "Point Guard"
            case .shootingGuard: return "Shooting Guard"
            }
        }
    }
}

League.teamA(.smallForward).description

//League.teamA(.allCases)
//League.teamB(.allCases)
```

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to achieve? `allCases` is an array, while at the moment your associated values are singular values, so you need to clarify if you want to be able to pass a single player or an array of players to the enum cases.

Comment: Exactly, get both an array with all the elements of a case `League.teamA (.allCases)` and the individual `League.teamA (. powerForward)`. `allcases` is not correct I know. What solution can i adopt?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to pass both a single instance an an array of instances, the easiest solution is to declare the associated type as an array, since then you can pass an array with a single element in case you just want to pass a single instance, or you can pass `allCases` as well.

```
enum PlayerA: CaseIterable {
    case center
    case powerForward
    case smallForward
}

extension PlayerA: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .center: return "Center"
        case .smallForward: return "Small Forward"
        case .powerForward: return "Power Forward"
        }
    }
}

enum PlayerB: CaseIterable {
    case pointGuard
    case shootingGuard
}

extension PlayerB: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .pointGuard: return "Point Guard"
        case .shootingGuard: return "Shooting Guard"
        }
    }
}

protocol EnumProtocol {
    var description: String { get }
}

enum League: EnumProtocol {
    case teamA([PlayerA])
    case teamB([PlayerB])
}

extension League: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case let .teamA(players):
            return players.description
        case let .teamB(players):
            return players.description
        }
    }
}

League.teamA([.smallForward]).description
League.teamA(PlayerA.allCases)
League.teamB(PlayerB.allCases)
```

Comment: thanks this might be fine, but maybe i'm using some wrong logic that doesn't allow me much flexibility. I will try to take a cue from [this](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/mixing-enums-with-other-swift-types/) too